# Unbind child nodes from pane

Tags: javafx

I have a pane where I add labels when I scroll to the left or right. When the labels are out of sight I remove them with pane.getChildren().clear(). The problem, that I have, is the memory, that is used, is increasing to the point where the garbage collector collects the removed objects and this leads to lags in my application. I was looking for a solution and found this link https://community.oracle.com/thread/2340686. This is similar to my problem but I don't know how to unbind the child nodes from a pane. Can someone tell me how to do it? It could help to solve the memory leak in my application

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Comment: You clear all labels every time **some label** leaves the viewport? Why not remove only items that are no longer in the viewport. Furthermore you should probably reuse labels that have left the screen by caching them and updating/readding them later. (Similar to what `ListView` does...)

Comment: I would do that but it is possible that I have 10000+ labels. I would prefer to remove them all and add the ~15 new labels that are visible. I tried getChildren().clear() and getChildren().removeAll() but it seems that they are bound to the pane. This could be the reason why they don't get collected right after I clear the pane.

Comment: curious: why so many labels? anyway, have a look at VirtualFlow/ContainerBase: they help you to re-use controls (vs. clear them)

Comment: Are you sure you can't just use a `ListView` with `HORIZONTAL` orientation for this? It already implements the efficiencies you are trying to make. This seems like a pretty complex wheel to be reinventing. (Apologies for the abuse of metaphor...)

Comment: Also, why would you expect them to be garbage collected as soon as they are removed from the pane? That would be extremely inefficient...

Comment: I thought the accumulation of labels that should get removed would lead to the lags in the application. I think I'm gonna try ListView. Maybe this will help to solve the problem. Thank you all in advance.